# How to call a SOAP web service from a Wordpress form?

Tags: wordpress, forms, soap

I have a Wordpress site that I am currently working on and have set up a form with the CformsII plugin but the client would like the form data submitted to a SOAP web service.

I have the SOAP webservice URL and XML data but the CformsII plugin in Wordpress seems to use a standard HTML POST method which I have been told that the SOAP webservicewill not handle.

I have never used or had any experience with SOAP web services before so I am really in need of guidance as to how I can go about submitting form data from a Wordpress site (with or without the CformsII plugin) to a SOAP webservice.

Has anyone achieved this previously or know of any plugin that could help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wish I had a better answer for you, but I'm afraid it'll involve some coding and understanding on SOAP. (Because I couldn't find any WordPress plugins that implemented a generic SOAP client or more specifically a form submitter with SOAP support).

This post author collected a nice group of links that should help get you started: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14804/embedding-a-soap-client-into-a-wordpress-plugin

Personally, I use [GravityForms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) for all my projects (but it's a paid plugin).  But they provide a nice API and there's a hook called [gform_post_submission](https://s3.amazonaws.com/gravityforms/documentation/gform_post_submission.pdf) that I've personally used a lot.  (I've "posted" to REST services using that hook).

Answer (score 3):

There is a soap plugin framework for wordpress that allows you to create/expose wordpress behavior as soap api. [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00D1AYIG8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00D1AYIG8) and http://github.com/patrickingle/wp-soap-services