# Log In form in WordPress that calls a Web service on submission

Tags: wordpress

I am having to create a login form on one of the pages of a wordpress site I have just inherited. I am absolutely new to both wordpress and php. The idea is to create a login form and on submission this would contact a .net web service which would then return a value saying whether the user is a valid one. (The .net part of it is all fine. I just tested it with a small php code snippet and it works). Based on the return value, I need to create an authentication ticket for the user in wordpress. How do I go about this? I seem to have no clue. I tried using the in built forms that comes with wordpress. As much as it is sophisticated, there is no apparent way to establish a soap connection to a Web service and all that. Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're able, but if you can you should definitely invest the time into converting this WordPress site into something you're more familiar with. Trying to get 2 separate systems to communicate like this will likely just cause more problems down the road as well as open potential security vulnerabilities, especially when you know absolutely nothing about one of the systems. Though if you absolutely _need_ to do it this way, I can link you to some related HTML/PHP and Wordpress tutorials.

Comment: I am not able to take that decision myself. I have been instructed to build this and anything I suggest will just be brushed aside, I am afraid. So, for now, I absolutely need to do it this way.

Comment: Alright. It was just some friendly input. I'll add an answer pointing you to some resources shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure where you'll have to start, or how much custom coding you'll have to do to get this to function the way you want, but understanding [SOAP in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) seems important. Understanding [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) would also be important. Also, having the [WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) as a reference would be a good idea.

As far as having WordPress use SOAP goes, I was able to find one [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585853/how-to-call-a-soap-web-service-from-a-wordpress-form) that may help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. Much appreciated. Just another quick question. When I want to create a php page in wordpress, how do I go about it? Do I have to create a template within the theme I use and use that template for my page?

Comment: Sorry, I had to leave right after this for work. Pages in Wordpress aren't really PHP pages; the content is stored in the database in the `wp_posts` table in the `post_content` column, and all of the HTML around the page content is stored in the theme templates. These template files can be found in `wp-content/themes/theme-directory`. A lot of themes are very messy, but I believe a lot of the framework themes are simple and good for beginners who want to customize their theme. You can find the codex for WordPress themes [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development).